# Три колонки одинаковой высоты. Как их сделать всегда одинаковой высоты?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

В футере есть три колонки #text-2, #text-3, #text-4. Нужно, чтобы они всегда были одной высоты, в независимости от контента, который находится внутри их. То есть #text-2 высота 200, #text-3 высота 300, #text-4 высота 400 - все должны быть высотой 400 пикселей. У меня два вопроса:

1. Как это реализовать с помощью jQuery?
2. Как полученный код jQuery сделать плагином Wordpress?

Comment: @eprivalov1, а почему с [помощью CSS сделать][1] не хотите? Или это из разряда: "*Мы не ищем лёгких путей?*" ;)

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/h5ey0ajd/

Answer (score 1):

Дурной способ найти самую высокую из них и поставить всем высоту этого элемента.

```
var max = Math.max.apply(
    Math, 
    jQuery('.footer-text').map(function() {
        return $(this).width();
    }));
jQuery('footer-text').css('height', max+'px');
```

Как-то так...
а как плагин из этого собрать 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668
и зарегистрирывать в вордпрессе скрипт с помощью функции http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = 0;
$('#text-2, #text-3, #text-4').each(function(){
    max = Math.max(max, $(this).height());
}).height(max);
```